# Jupyter Notebook - underscore.js doesn't seem to be accessible anymore

Tags: javascript, python, jupyter-notebook, underscore.js, jupyter-widget

I'm using a custom widget in Jupyter. After upgrading to a new machine it stopped functioning. Checking the javascript console in the browser window running the notebook I see the error `ReferenceError: _ is not defined`. Indeed, running the following in a Jupyter cell:

```
%%js
alert(_)
```

I get the same error. Doing the exact same command on my other machine functions correctly (it shows the definition of _ as in underscore.js).
The html source of the Jupyter Notebook still shows underscore.js as being specified in the `require.config`. Note that simple included widgets still function as expected (so it is not an issue with initializing the widget system).

I haven't found anything in the changelogs of ipywidgets or jupyter regarding changes to the use of underscore.js. I know that the widget api has changed recently in `ipywidgets8.0`, which is why I am still using version 7.7.3.

Does anyone know if this is an expected change of behaviour in how widgets work? Any other ideas of why underscore does not seem to be initialized properly?

Comment: I encountered the same error. `pip install notebook==6.4.11` is the last version that worked for me. It seems like js assets were delegated to NbClassic since 6.5.x: see https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/pull/6474.

Comment: Thanks for that link. I'm on `notebook==6.4.12` and that also works. So it looks like the 6.5.x branch might have broken this.

Comment: Downgrading on my other machine to 6.4.12 fixed the issue. @obk if you leave an answer I will accept it as it resolved my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Underscore.js is available in the 6.4.x series e.g. `pip install notebook=6.4.12`

It broke in your case likely because js assets were delegated to NbClassic starting with 6.5, which I'm guessing doesn't load underscore.js (or doesn't make it available to the notebook frontend). See github.com/jupyter/notebook/pull/6474.